# beginning to make a 3d game

Tags: 3d, game-engine

i want to make a 3d game and am uncertain of where to start

i definately dont wanna make my own engine because i feel like i reinvent the wheel so i looked at some of the free engines out there but i have no idea of how to decide which to choose

i will want to have a very huge world in which u can walk around, with water and everything u find in nature, also some nice physics and sounds and music and special effects, particle systems, everything :D

i might want to render a huge area at one time, or better i would like it so u can see endlessly far into the distance, maybe u can only render the rough shapes of things when they are far away or something?

they say that the irrlicht graphics engine has great performance which is important to me

im not very experienced but very smart, i know a bit c++ and opengl, which engine would be best to make a huge game? any advice on anything would be great and much appriciated!

Comment: Very open ended question as there are a lot of graphics engines to choose from that are both free or paid for. Try them out and find one you like the most, then narrow your question down some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not a very experienced programmer I would start with something like Microsoft's XNA framework and build a 2D side scroller first.  Everyone wants to jump right into 3D without realizing the complexities adding another dimension creates.

You can also checkout Unreal's Developer Kit (http://www.unrealengine.com/en/udk/downloads/).  This is the same Unreal Engine used by many of today's games (minus a couple licensed features), but you can create some pretty impressive stuff with it.